# Grouping nodes in force directed graphs in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I have currently started working with d3.js.
How to group nodes to give different colours in force directed graph? For example: parent node having red colour while child node having blue.

Comment: Do you want to color the nodes based on data, or hierarchical level, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

A a follow up to nrabinowitz, in a graph you don't have parent/child relationships. You do in a *directed* graph, such as a tree.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Romain and assuming you are indeed working with a directed graph, you can group the nodes by assigning a number to each node in your data.

```
var nodes = [
{"name":"node1","group":"2"},
{"name":"node2","group":"4"},
{"name":"node3","group":"5"}]
```

Check out this example: https://jsfiddle.net/4xt5v51m/